# PHP: List multiple record grouped by date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to list multiple record from MySQL Database using PHP but when grouping it returns only one record from database, below is my PHP code I'm using.

```
<?php
                include "connection.php";               
                
                $query = "select * from lectureupload GROUP BY submittedOn";
                
                $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                    
                    
                    echo '<table class="table">';                                               
                    echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<td><strong>ID</strong></td>';
                    echo '<td><strong>Title</strong></td>';
                    echo '<td><strong>Semester</strong></td>';
                    echo '<td><strong>Teacher</strong></td>';
                    echo '<td><strong>Lecture Link</strong></td>';
                    echo '<td><strong>Submitted On</strong></td>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                                            
                    echo '<div class="section-header">';
                        echo '<br>';
                        echo '<h3>'.$row['submittedOn'].'</h3>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    
                    echo '<tr >';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['semester'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['teacherName'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td><a href="'.$row['lectureLink'].'">'.$row['lectureLink'].'</a></td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['submittedOn'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    
                    echo '</table>';
                }
                
                
                        
                mysqli_close($conn);
                
            ?>
```

The current Result it gives me is somewhat like that,

[image]

My Database table is this.

[image]

Solution to this problem will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Where is the `group by` clause?

Comment: I don't see an error in your result screenshot. It does list two results like you would expect from a group by query.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I updated the code mistakenly copied query wrong. The result I want is that It should list all records in the above dates Eg. 29-6-2020 there are two records on that date and 2 records in 6-7-2020 as well. but showing only one.

Comment: Remove the group by and all records will be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use GROUP BY clause to retrieve all records from that table. GROUP BY will always return one row per GROUP BY CONDITIONAL_COLUMN. I will suggest you below modification:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

//ORDER BY submittedOn will make sure the records retrieved in ordered as per submittedOn.
$query = "select * from lectureupload ORDER BY submittedOn";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$submitted_on_keys = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!in_array($row['submittedOn'], $submitted_on_keys)) {
        if (count($submitted_on_keys) > 0) {
            //It means we have already created <table> which needs to be closed.
            echo '</table>';
        }
        $submitted_on_keys[] = $row['submittedOn'];

        echo '<table class="table">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<td><strong>ID</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Title</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Semester</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Teacher</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Lecture Link</strong></td>';
        echo '<td><strong>Submitted On</strong></td>';
        echo '</thead>';

        echo '<div class="section-header">';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<h3>' . $row['submittedOn'] . '</h3>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '<tr >';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['semester'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['teacherName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="' . $row['lectureLink'] . '">' . $row['lectureLink'] . '</a></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['submittedOn'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}

if (count($submitted_on_keys) > 0) {
    //There is last <table> which needs to be closed.
    echo '</table>';
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should group it in your PHP code rather than your SQL.

Something like this:

```
$lectures = [];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from lectureupload");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $lectures[$row['submittedOn']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($lectures as $submittedOn => $rows) {
    echo '<table class="table">';                                               
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<td><strong>ID</strong></td>';
    echo '<td><strong>Title</strong></td>';
    echo '<td><strong>Semester</strong></td>';
    echo '<td><strong>Teacher</strong></td>';
    echo '<td><strong>Lecture Link</strong></td>';
    echo '<td><strong>Submitted On</strong></td>';
    echo '</thead>';
                            
    echo '<div class="section-header">';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<h3>'.$submittedOn.'</h3>';
    echo '</div>';
    
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<tr >';
        echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['semester'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['teacherName'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.$row['lectureLink'].'">'.$row['lectureLink'].'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['submittedOn'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    
    echo '</table>';
}
```